# How to declare cascade delete in EF when child table isn't mapped as separate entity

Tags: entity-framework, cascade

I have got a database first approach with EF5 and here is a fragment of mappings:

```
internal class xxxMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Order>
{
    public xxxMapping ()
    {
        ToTable("my_table");

        //......

        HasMany(it => it.Documents)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(
                m =>
                {
                    m.ToTable("dependent_table");
                    m.MapLeftKey("left_key_id");
                    m.MapRightKey("right_key_id");
                });
     }
```

What is the best way to declare, using fluent API, that when some row is deleted from *my_table*, then dependent rows from *dependent_table* will be deleted too (Cascade delete option in FK)

UPD It seems to be working without any additional code (Of course - if foreign key in table is configured properly). But i'm not sure it's a good practice to do so

Comment: what about [WillCascadeOnDelete(true)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679204(v=vs.113).aspx) ?

Comment: Can you please clarify - in what place should i use  WillCascadeOnDelete(true)?

Comment: after `Map(...).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);`

Comment: No, this doesn't work. **.Map(...)** returns void, so extenion method cannot be applied

Comment: and so do WillCascadeOndelete. May be you can let EF do the mapping, that is no use Map. Otherwise I don't know.